# Ubuntu 17.04 Wifi Not visible

Tags: networking, network-manager

I have a Ubuntu 17.04 machine. And Wifi option is not visible. It worked before. I tried following commands.

[image]

```
sudo service networking restart
sudo service network-manager restart
```

And the `ifconfig` command output as follows.

[image]

Running Wireless Info Script gives the following result.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 22 Sep 2017 02:19 +0530 +0530

Booted last: 22 Sep 2017 00:00 +0530 +0530

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.10.0-35-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 13 07:46:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Realtek 802.11 b/g/n w/ *2 antennas
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8188EE mini-PCIe card [103c:197d]

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    DeviceName: Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:2186]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:b40d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
rtl8188ee              90112  0
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8188ee
rtlwifi                73728  2 rtl_pci,rtl8188ee
mac80211              782336  3 rtl_pci,rtl8188ee,rtlwifi
cfg80211              602112  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
wmi                    16384  1 hp_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether <MAC address>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 340  bytes 25040 (25.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 340  bytes 25040 (25.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.9  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fd9c:c172:9a22:da00:d2c9:2393:6511:b63c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::2169:42ad:60bd:96c3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd9c:c172:9a22:da00:dc56:8d9e:e455:32d0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether <MAC address>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4010  bytes 4105414 (4.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3872  bytes 482924 (482.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"BELL4G"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'BELL4G' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=135 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-20 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.0.53

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       818     1  0 02:16 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (RTL8188EE mini-PCIe card)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtl8188ee
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.10.0-35-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/wlan0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlan0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     BELL4G
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       02b9fe29-6c23-4701-98a7-14961e16ef44
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     135 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   02b9fe29-6c23-4701-98a7-14961e16ef44 | BELL4G
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.9/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             119.235.0.4
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.8.8
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1506113172
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.9
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 43200
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       domain_name_servers = 119.235.0.4 8.8.8.8
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 75600
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fd9c:c172:9a22:da00:dc56:8d9e:e455:32d0/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         fd9c:c172:9a22:da00:d2c9:2393:6511:b63c/64
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         fe80::2169:42ad:60bd:96c3/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fd9c:c172:9a22:da00::/64, nh = ::, mt = 600
IP6.DNS[1]:                             fe80::1
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        requested_dhcp6_domain_search = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = fe80::1
DHCP6.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp6_server_id = 0:1:0:1:17:c2:8c:85:9c:c1:72:9a:22:da
DHCP6.OPTION[4]:                        requested_dhcp6_client_id = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[5]:                        requested_dhcp6_name_servers = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[6]:                        dhcp6_client_id = 0:4:c2:95:f3:15:e1:77:c7:37:bb:a0:b1:90:3e:a9:fb:ec

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /virtual/device/placeholder/1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       eth0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     no
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

SSID    BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
BELL4G  <MAC 'BELL4G' [AC1]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  96      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2  yes     * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/BELL4G]] (600 root)
[connection] id=BELL4G | type=wifi | permissions=user:isuru:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=BELL4G
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Colombo (based on set time zone)

global
country US: DFS-FCC
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     11 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'BELL4G' [AC1]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-22 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"BELL4G"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000c7f0d295d
                    Extra: Last beacon: 40ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'SLT-4G_10CDEF' [AC2]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=28/70  Signal level=-82 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"SLT-4G_10CDEF"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000ba78ea187
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1192ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8188ee]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-35-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8188ee/rtl8188ee.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin
description:    Realtek 8188E 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         zhiyuan_yang    <zhiyuan_yang@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     CEF47E154DF31A67353AC40
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl_pci,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-35-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
 (bool)

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-35-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     B93F82B28F7945C22514E4D
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-35-generic SMP mod_unload 

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-35-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     884DE3F31278351A45DA409
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-35-generic SMP mod_unload 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-35-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     309C9ACED540FCAA1DE7422
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-35-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-35-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     D77C8F93375950F3BA95B16
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-35-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rtl8188ee]
debug: 0
disable_watchdog: N
fwlps: N
ips: N
msi: Y
swenc: N
swlps: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf]
options cirrus modeset=1
options mgag200 modeset=1

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8136 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8179 (rtl8188ee)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   23.337682] rtl8188ee: rtl8188ee: Power Save off (module option)
[   23.337684] rtl8188ee: rtl8188ee: FW Power Save off (module option)
[   23.338436] rtl8188ee: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin
[   23.391465] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   23.392199] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[   31.180585] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready (repeated 5 times)
[   36.608213] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'BELL4G' [AC1]>
[   36.618421] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'BELL4G' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   36.620004] wlan0: authenticated
[   36.620484] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'BELL4G' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   36.624316] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'BELL4G' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[   36.624622] wlan0: associated
[   36.624744] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Start here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Answer (score 0):

Best way to start running a `dmesg` command from your terminal. If you looks for red line, you will be able easily to find errors, try to find anything related to your wireless card, like missing firmware. Realtek Wireless often needs a firmware, try to locate the file name and if you are not able to install the file, edit your post.